# Order by and if some are the same then order by something else in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Hi I am looking to sort a table of players on my site.

For instance people are predicting scores, I have everything set and working but was wondering if its possible to set an order and if the order has 2 the same, then order them 2 by something else.

For instance here is the query I am using just to order.

```
"SELECT * FROM league ORDER BY points DESC";
```

Now if a user has the same points I would then like to go for goal difference, if that is the same go for goals scored, and if that is the same finally go for persons name.

Is this possible in sql or is this a php algorithm I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to order on multiple columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM league
ORDER BY points DESC, goalDiff DESC, goalsScored DESC, playerName
```

Comment: I did not know you can nest an orderby like this. Thank you

Comment: What's the error message exactly?  Also, ASC is the default so you can leave that out if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

see the below syntax-

```
SELECT column-list 
FROM table_name 
[WHERE condition] 
[ORDER BY column1, column2, .. columnN] [ASC | DESC];
```

For more detail check the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm)

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding :)